# Activate multiple routes at once in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to open two child routes within named router outlets at once. This will allow me to have `router outlet A` always be filled with a content specific component e.g. `login`.

The second `router outlet B` would then have a reusable component that processes the `data {...}` given with it in the route configuration. (so still dependent on the specific route).

This mean that route `/login` should use `FrameComponent` as the layout frame and load one component into `router outlet view` and one into `router outlet control-strip`.

My `FrameComponent`'s layout currently looks like this:

```
<router-outlet name="view"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="control-strip"></router-outlet>
```

and my router configuration looks like this:

```
...
{
    path: 'login',
    component: FrameComponent,
    canActivate: [ UIGuard, hasInternetConnection, authLoggedOutService ],
    data: {
        navigationBack: true
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: '**',
            component: LoginEmailComponent,
            outlet: 'view'
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            component: ControlStripComponent,
            outlet: 'control-strip'
        }
    ]
},
...
```

**The problem I'm facing is that the router configuration stops on the first hit, so `/login/**` is true and the ControlStripComponent never gets touched.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing the concept of child routes with the concept of secondary (or auxiliary) routes. It sounds like you should be using secondary routes here and *not* child routes.

This is the syntax you need for navigating to an auxiliary route:

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: { popup: ['messages']}}]);
```

Or to navigate to two auxiliary routes at once:

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: { view: ['routeA'], control-strip: ['routeB']}}]);
```

Where the configuration looks something like this:

```
    {
        path: 'routeA',
        component: LoginEmailComponent,
        outlet: 'view'
    },
    {
        path: 'routeB',
        component: ControlStripComponent,
        outlet: 'control-strip'
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but this means that the code somewhere determines what the next routes are, and these can be independent. I however want every route to have two specific components loaded every time. These two routes are always linked in the same way. This doesn't really seem like a clean solution.Unless I of course write a piece of code that runs on every parent route and activates it sub /control-strip that has a consistent name but varying name dependent on the parent.

Comment: If the two components are "linked", could you use a nested component instead of a route?

Comment: The problem with that is that I cannot send data or parameters via regular nested components.

Comment: You can through @input properties.But I don't understand enough about your app to really suggest a solution.